# How to use if condition in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

3 login based questions in the website to be automated

I need correct code to automate these.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTQWv.jpg)

Comment: Can show me the code in selenium IDE

Answer (score 0):

When using "if ..." Commands in test steps in Selenium IDE for Chrome, you need to remember the following:

1. Use "if ... end" to form a single branch of test steps.
2. Use "if ... else ... end" to form two branches of test steps.
3. Use "if ... else if ... else ... end" to form multiple branches of test steps.
4. Use JavaScript Boolean expression syntax to specify conditions to "if" and "else if" commands.
5. ${variable} is allowed in condition expressions.

Here is a sample test called "Condition" on how to use variables:

```
1   execute script | return (new Date()).getDay(); | day 
2   echo | ${day}
3   if | ${day} < 1
4     echo | Sunday
5   else if | ${day} > 5
6     echo | Saturday
7   else 
8     echo Weekday
9   end
```

Here is the log output when you execute the above test.

```
1. executeScript on return (new Date()).getDay(); with value day OK
echo: 0
3. if on ${day} < 1 OK
echo: Sunday
5. elseIf on ${day} > 5 OK
7. else OK
9. end OK
```

Comment: Getting "failed: invalid or unexpected token" error in ' if statement ' code - if| ${var} === "statement".        @mostafa faryabi thanks